# Deploying React and Express APP To IIS - New images not rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, iis

I have a full stack application that uses Node, Express, and React. When I run the code locally from VScode my application does all functions such as updating to database, uploading images to folders, etc.

When I build the app and link the build folder into IIS 90% of the app works. The only function that isnt working is the ability to upload images. The backend API is successful and the file is uploaded (outside of the build folder) into Public folder, but then the image never renders. If I go into developer tools and change the file name to an existing image name it will render the image. This makes no sense to me.

Structure:

Public/
-File1.jpg (This file existed before build/launch into IIS)
-File2.jpg (This file was added after build/launch via API & middleware)

(THIS WORKS & renders image)
 (THIS DOES NOT WORKS & NO IMAGE rendered but it exists in the folder)

I have a feeling its something to do with my IIS configuration but im lost.

web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMaxAge="0" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Rewrite all non-existing files and directories to the root -->
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api" negate="true" /> <!-- Exclude API routes from the rewrite -->
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

server.js snip it code (This declares the folder location - this works)

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const folder = determineUploadFolder(file); // Determine the folder dynamically based on the file
    cb(null, '../public/img/corporate-events');
    console.log('File folder destination: '+folder)
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file);
    const folder = determineUploadFolder(file); // Determine the folder dynamically based on the file
    const filePath = path.join(`${folder}`, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    cb(null, filePath);
    console.log('File name: '+ filePath)
  }
});
```

Ive tried uploading the images to builder/img but that still does not work.

If i cannot get this to work I might just try to do a reverse proxy but that seems like another headache.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when the new images are not rendered? It is not possible to troubleshoot your issue based on this url rewrite rule alone.

Comment: I have concluded that the issue is definetly permission related. When I created a IIS_IUSRS permission with full allow permissions, none of the images loaded. Still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Since you created the IIS_IUSRS permission with full permission, the image still doesn't load, are you sure it's a permission issue? or you got it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

My images names were all named with only integers values such as 12345.jpg

IIS does not like this so I appended letters to the names and now they render.